# Broker Vs Gateway pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture

I'm a bit confused about those two - [Broker](http://www.openloop.com/softwareEngineering/patterns/architecturePattern/arch_Broker.htm) and [Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html) EAA patterns. It seems that Broker can:

> structure distributed software systems with decoupled components that interact by remote service invocations

and Gateway

> Wrap all the special API code into a class whose interface looks like a regular object. Other objects access the resource through this Gateway, which translates the simple method calls into the appropriate specialized API.

If so - how they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Fowler got it right. Gateway has nothing to do with classes/objects. What he describes is Facade design pattern - makes interface simpler.

When you think about architecture patterns, think about nodes. When you think about design patterns, think about classes/objects. Node is an abstraction of: device - hardware stuff and system software - e.g. OS, platform/framework etc. System software is "assigned" to the device. Node "encapsulates" device and system software and is related to other nodes comprising the architecture.

Gateway is a node that insulates server nodes from client nodes - client node cannot directly connect to a server node. Gateway receives the connection and then establishes connection itself to the destination node. Broker is much more flexible, as described.